# >>= operator in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def partitions(set_):
    if not set_:
        yield []
        return
    for i in range(2**len(set_)//2):
        parts = [set(), set()]
        for item in set_:
            parts[i&1].add(item)
            i >>= 1
        for b in partitions(parts[1]):
            yield [parts[0]]+b

def get_partitions(set_):
    for partition in partitions(set_):
        yield [list(elt) for elt in partition]
```

I'm trying to understand what "i >>= 1" does in this code. Can someone explain this to me?

Edit: Can someone explain what "parts[i&1]" does as well?

Comment: it's [right, bitwise shift](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) augmented assignment. So, like `x += 1` is the same as `x = x + 1`, this is the same as `i = i >> 1`

Comment: Thanks! Can u explain what "parts[i&1]" does as well?

Comment: `i & 1` means `Bitwise AND` of `i` and `1`. For example, 2 in binary = `0010` and 6 is `0110`. So `2 & 6 = 2`. In the same way, `i & 1` is extracting the LSB (least significant bit) of the number (either 1 or 0).

Answer (score 0):

`i >>= 1` is the assignment operator shorthand for `i = i >> 1`, where `>>` is the bitwise right shift operator. Bitwise shifting `i` to the right by 1 has the same effect as integer dividing `i` by 2.